# Where is Chrome push cache stored physically?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser-cache, http2

> The Push cache (better described as the “unclaimed push streams container”, but that’s less catchy as names go) is where HTTP/2 push resources are stored. They are stored as part of an HTTP/2 session, which has several implications.

What is this “unclaimed push streams container”  and is it stored on hdd/sdd or in RAM?

Answer (score 1):

Given that it’s bound to the connection and is dropped once the connection is closed I’d imagine it’s stored in RAM or a temporary disk location rather than in a permanent disk location that is accessible.

Only once a pushed resource is claimed is it put into the normal HTTP cache (depending on cache headers).